# Error when updating to QGIS 2.8.4

Tags: qgis

I'm updating on Ubuntu `14.04` , but I have these tracebacks for `QGis` :

```
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-provider-grass_2.8.4+20trusty_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-divert: error: `diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-provider-grass' clashes with `diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-plugin-grass'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/qgis-provider-grass_2.8.4+20trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

and it finishes like this :

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/qgis-provider-grass_2.8.4+20trusty_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with the 2.8.4 update from 2.8.3. Here's how I fixed it:

You'll notice in the traceback it says

```
dpkg-divert: error: `diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-provider-grass' clashes with `diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-plugin-grass'
```

The divert functionality of dpkg is basically just a renaming of packages. In this case, the qgis-provider-grass package is trying to rename /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin, but it found that this renaming is clashing with a similar rule put in place by qgis-plugin-grass.

The solution is, remove the existing divert, and allow the qgis-provider-grass to put it in again. This doesn't actually break anything (in the extreme case, you can remove the divert altogether and then you'll be calling /usr/bin/qgis instead of /usr/bin/qgis.bin)

To remove the divert, run

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove --rename /usr/bin/qgis
```

You should see a message like this

```
Removing 'diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-plugin-grass'
```

Also, you'll want to do the same thing for qbrowser (you'll find that if you don't, another error like the one you're seeing will pop up):

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove --rename /usr/bin/qbrowser
```

That's it! Now, fix all the broken packages in apt (they're not actually broken, but apt thinks they are because it couldn't run the divert rule):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

What worked for me was to remove all `qgis` and `grass` related packages (I used `synaptic`, it helped me to find them).

I then made a fresh install of the ltr following the instructions on http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. I made sure to only have the deb and deb-src of http://qgis.org/debian-ltr active in the sources.list

Comment: I had done that. i.e autoremove `qgis*` and `grass*` . But when I install, I still have the `qgis-plugin-grass` and `qgis-provider-grass` which yields an incompatibility error. Thanks for the advice.